# SectionList: props.sections.reduce is not a function

Tags: react-native

I've been pulling data from my rails API to render in a list of already made contacts. I've been able to render the contact data easily enough on a FlatList, but now I want to order and display the data in an alphabetical SectionList depending on the first letter of the contact name.

I have managed to get rails to give me the JSON correctly (?). But getting stuck rendering the section list. I'm not sure if I need to restructure the JSON response or if I'm missing something simple in `renderSectionHeader`

**This is the JSON:**

```
contacts: {
      data: {
        J: [
          {
            id: 1,
            email: 'js@me.com',
            password_digest: '-',
            phone_number: '+1',
            name: 'Jay',
            circle_id: 'Jay',
            bio: null,
            created_at: '2020-07-17T11:05:47.479Z',
            updated_at: '2020-07-17T20:22:25.821Z'
          }
        ],
        K: [
          {
            id: 1,
            email: 'kk@me.com',
            password_digest: '-',
            phone_number: '+2',
            name: 'Kay',
            circle_id: 'Kay',
            bio: null,
            created_at: '2020-07-17T11:05:48.479Z',
            updated_at: '2020-07-17T20:22:28.821Z'
          }
        ]
```

**This is the SectionList:**

```
<SectionList style={{width: '100%', marginTop: 10 }}
             sections={this.props.contacts.data}
             renderItem={({item}) =>
                         <TouchableOpacity>
                              <ContactBasic item={item}/>
                         </TouchableOpacity>}
             renderSectionHeader={({section}) => (
                         <Text style={styles.sectionHeader}>{section.data}</Text>)}
             keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
             ListEmptyComponent={() => (
                         <View>
                              <Button title="No Contacts Found" type="clear"/>
                         </View>
                       )}
                     />
```

**This is the ContactBasic Component:**

```
<View style={styles.contactContainer}>
     <View style={styles.contact}>
           <Image style={styles.image}/>
           <View style={styles.contactText}>
                <Text style={styles.contactName}>{props.item.name}</Text>
           </View>
     </View>
</View>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your json structure is not compatible
you have an object as data not an array

```
data: {
        J: [
          {}
 }
```

You will have to convert it to a structure like below

```
data: [
          {title:'J',contacts:[]}
]
```

When section list calls the reduce function in the array it throws the error.
If you can handle this on the api level it would be easy, otherwise you will have to do this at JS level.

Comment: You can refer this answer for mapping at JS level https://stackoverflow.com/a/62760755/1435722

Comment: Will do through API as it will make more sense in long run. Thanks for your answer!